# how to limit my bandwidth to test mywebsite / applications

Tags: internet, networking, bandwidth

I developed an application that uses a website API and I got feedbacks that it freezes for almost 30 seconds, and that is due to their poor bandwidth (5Ko/sec downloading).

I have a good internet speed, so a feed with 1Mo wont make more than 3 seconds, I want to know if there is any software that allow me to limit the bandwidth that I want, even under 10Ko/sec.

what's the best app for that?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I'am using windows 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are on Windows XP or Vista since if it were something more interesting (linux or Mac) you would have said so.

I haven't tried it myself, but this may do what you need and it is free:
[Bandwidth Shaper XP](http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html)

Comment: +1 for 'something more interesting' :)

Comment: thank you, I think this will do it, btw I'm on windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about an app but you could try to use functions of your router to limit bandwidth, especially with some of the Linksys models like WRT54G that can be loaded with 3rd party firmware for extra features like that. Maybe use QoS somehow?

Comment: +1 - Router-based solutions are the most painless - no additional software to add, assuming your router supports it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Network Emulator tool kit to do this.

YOu can find an article explaining how to use it here. http://www.gonetdotnet.info/posts/how-to-test-an-application-in-limited-bandwidth

Comment: See http://superuser.com/faq#promotion. Since it's your own site, at least add a disclaimer. Also, it would be a more useful answer if you would actually explain here, and not just give a link.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.